# Thread.Sleep for Google MAPS API

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3

I am using GoogleAPI to get the Driving Miles and Driving Distance. Here is my Source Code...

```
 dsAPI.ReadXml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + strBaseLat + "," + strBaseLong + "&destination=" + strDStrLat + "," + strDStrLong + "&sensor=false");
 Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Edited Code :

```
dsAPI.ReadXml("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" + strBaseLat + "," + strBaseLong + "&destination=" + strDStrLat + "," + strDStrLong + "&sensor=false");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            if (dsAPI.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                status = dsAPI.Tables[0].Rows[0]["status"].ToString();
            }
            if (status == "OK")
            {
                if (dsAPI.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    legid = Convert.ToInt32(dsAPI.Tables[2].Rows[0]["leg_Id"].ToString());
                }

                if (dsAPI.Tables[7].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataView dvMinutes = new DataView(dsAPI.Tables[7]);
                    dvMinutes.RowFilter = "leg_Id = '" + legid + "'";
                    decMinutes = Convert.ToDecimal(dvMinutes[0]["value"] as string);
                    Min = decMinutes / 60;
                    Min = decimal.Round(Min, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

                }
                if (dsAPI.Tables[8].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataView dvMiles = new DataView(dsAPI.Tables[8]);
                    dvMiles.RowFilter = "leg_Id = '" + legid + "'";
                    intMiles = Convert.ToInt32(dvMiles[0]["value"] as string);
                    Mil = Convert.ToDecimal(intMiles / 1609.34);
                    Mil = decimal.Round(Mil, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                }
```

Based on the latitude and longitude, the API will return the details. In the next line i had given Thread.sleep.

if i dint give thread.sleep,whether the remaining part of the code will wait, till the service returns the result. I had checked in my code, sometimes the remaining part got executed without waiting for the result.

Is there any alternative for this.

Comment: can you show the implementation of the dsAPI? because you should resolve it in the dsAPI.ReadXml method

Comment: i had edited my above code...

Comment: What I meant is that you should provide the code which actually get the directions from url - what is the implementation of the ReadXml method? Or at least the name of the library.

Comment: I cant able to understand what you are asking...I am just passing the latitude and longitude to Google Maps API. It will return the result in XML format. I am just taking that XML tag and saving to database..

Comment: and which language do you use? :)

Comment: dsAPI is just a dataset--DataSet dsAPI = new DataSet(); ...Working in .Net

Comment: Ok, with .Net I'm not able to help you (not my language :)). But try to introduce intermediate step: download file, and then read it, and check if the problem is really with parsing xml (maybe you just receive empty xml file).